# entity framework code first double many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework-5, code-first

I'm using Entity framwork 5 code first and i have 2 tables: Customer and Dossier. And i have 2 relationships of type many-to-many between them:

```
public class Customer {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Dossier> Debtors { get; set; }
    public List<Dossier> Creditors { get; set; }
}

public class Dossier {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Customer> Debtors { get; set; }
    public List<Customer> Creditors { get; set; }
}
```

How can i achieve this using code first?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to show what you've tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve that using two relation tables, one for the Debtors and one for the Creditors.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasMany(c => c.Debtors).WithMany(d => d.Debtors).Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("CustomerId").MapRightKey("DossierId").ToTable("DebtorCustomerDossierRel"));

modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasMany(c => c.Creditors).WithMany(d => d.Creditors).Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("CustomerId").MapRightKey("DossierId").ToTable("CreditorCustomerDossierRel"));
```

I haven't tried this code, but it should work pretty close to that.

This would be in your DbContext.OnModelCreating method (for that are new to Code First).